# Allow users to edit content of tweet with update_with_media

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am using the twitter gem to tweet with media. The code is currently working however it does not bring up the tweet sheet allowing the user to edit the content of the tweet before being sent. What do I need to add to allow the user to edit the outgoing tweet?

Here is my code:

User Model

```
def tweet_micard
    micard_image = self.s3_images.last.image_url 
    uri = URI.parse(micard_image)
    media = uri.open 
    media.instance_eval("def original_filename; '#{File.basename(uri.path)}'; end")
    twitter_client.update_with_media("future tweet goes here", media)
  end

  def twitter_client
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "..."
      config.consumer_secret     = "..."
      config.access_token        = self.oauth_token
      config.access_token_secret = self.oauth_secret
    end
    client
  end
```

Twitter Controller

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check

  def callback
    current_user.update_attributes(oauth_token: env['omniauth.auth'][:credentials][:token], oauth_secret: env['omniauth.auth'][:credentials][:secret])
    current_user.tweet_micard
    redirect_to micard_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at this time.
as stated here.

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/19808